# Accumulating multiple columns of the same type of data in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, accumulate

I am a relative newcomer to R so I'm probably asking one of the easiest things here. I have 10 columns of the same type of data that I would like to accumulate under one name. The column headings are:

egg_diameter1, egg_diameter2...egg_diameter10

How can I accumulate this under one common name? Say egg.diameter
There are also a load of zero values that I would like to eliminate from the study as well. Can anybody include the code for this as well?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `10` columns to be reduced to `1` column

```
 dat1 <- data.frame(egg.diameter=unlist(dat, use.names=FALSE))
```

Or

```
  dat2 <- setNames(stack(dat)[,1,drop=FALSE], "egg.diameter")
```

If you want to remove the `0` values

```
  dat2[dat2[,1]!=0,,drop=FALSE]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:40, 10*20,replace=TRUE),
          ncol=10, dimnames=list(NULL, paste("egg", paste0("diameter",1:10)))))
```